# Is there a way to avoid duplicate data on the 1st and 2nd tab? PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am creating a shopping cart like program, so after i request or sent a request for reservation then the data will be put on the 2nd tab. I have already done that, but the problem is that I need to remove the choosed data on the 1st tab. Here is an image for visual reference:

> So the output should be: on the 1st tab, EO1 should only be available, and the highlited red circles should be placed on tab 2.

[image]

Then my 2nd Tab

[image]

> I have already tried using new Array and Array push and in Array it but still giving the problem which the 1st tab data is still showing, how can I hide or remove the data that has been chosen from the 1st tab? here is my code

View

1st Tab

```
<?php $newArray = array(); ?>

 <?php foreach($dorms as $dorm): ?>
  
    <?php 
        $res = $dorm['code'];
        array_push($newArray, $res);
    ?>

  <a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pages/view/<?php echo $dorm['id']; ?>">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4" style="margin-left: 6rem;padding-bottom: 1rem;">
      <div class="card top-shadow" style="width: 12rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/dorms/<?php echo $dorm['image'] ?>" style="border-radius: 15%;width:100px;height:100px;">
          <hr class="border-black">
          <h5 class="card-title color-black">Room Type: <b><?php echo $dorm['type']; ?></b></h5>
          <h5 class="card-title color-black">Room Cost: <br><b> P <?php echo $dorm['price']; ?>.00</b></h5>

          <?php if ($dorm['status'] == 0): ?>
              <h5 class="card-title color-black"> <b>  <span class="badge badge-success">Reserve Now</span>  </b></h5>
          <?php elseif ($dorm['status'] == 1): ?>
               <h5 class="card-title color-black"> <b>  <span class="badge badge-info">Pending Reservation</span>  </b></h5>
          <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

2nd Tab

```
<?php foreach($dormreserved as $dormres): ?>
 
  <?php
      $pos = $dormres['code'];  
  ?>

  <?php if(in_array($pos, $newArray)): ?>

    <a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pages/view/<?php echo $dormres['id']; ?>">
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-4" style="margin-left: 6rem;padding-bottom: 1rem;">
        <div class="card top-shadow" style="width: 12rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/dorms/<?php echo $dormres['image'] ?>" style="border-radius: 15%;width:100px;height:100px;">
            <hr class="border-black">

            <h5 class="card-title color-black">Room Type: <b><?php echo $dormres['code']; ?></b></h5>
            <h5 class="card-title color-black">Room Type: <b><?php echo $dormres['type']; ?></b></h5>
            <h5 class="card-title color-black">Room Cost: <br><b> P <?php echo $dormres['price']; ?>.00</b></h5>

            
              <h5 class="card-title color-black"> <b>  <span class="badge badge-info">Pending Reservation</span>  </b></h5>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller

```
public function home()
{
    // Check login
    if(!$this->session->userdata('student_logged_in')){
        redirect('students/login');
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Home';
    
    $data['dorms'] = $this->dorm_model->get_dorms();
    $data['dormreserved'] = $this->dorm_model->get_reserves();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('students/pages/home', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Model

```
public function get_dorms(){
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('dorms');
    return $query->result_array();
}


public function get_reserves(){
    $this->db->join('reserves', 'reserves.dorm_id = dorms.id');
    $this->db->where('reserves.tenant_id', $this->session->userdata('student_user_id'));
    $query = $this->db->get('dorms');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Filtering should be done in your controller or possibly in your model queries, but not in your view.  Are you filtering the second tab's data based on duplicate `code` column values?

Comment: you need to write `not exists` for first tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update `get_dorms` function

```
public function get_dorms(){
    $this->db->where('id NOT IN(select dorm_id from reserves)');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('dorms');
    return $query->result_array();
 }
```

Comment: reserves table store the reserve dorms and for first tab show only not reserved dorms. so in  this function i have get all dorms from dorms table, but in where condition the dorms that are not in reserved table.

Comment: Hello, your code works but there's a problem when I change user account, then the choosed data is also not there, it should be there because the other account has not yet do some transactions. How can we solve that problem?

Comment: here is the link can you help me to get a solution . [Link new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754238/is-there-a-way-to-view-data-uniquely-from-depending-on-the-user-accounts-codeig)