# Is there a way to view data uniquely from depending on the user accounts? Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two tabs, I am trying to create a room reservation, so when the `user1` logged in and will choose a room he will be directed on the first tab, then he/she can request for a room then, after it has successfully requested a room, it will go to the second tab for viewing. I have successfully done that.

The problem is: When I change any user accounts, then the available data that are showin in tab 1 is placed in tab 2 like what `user1` is viewing. How is it that? when `user2` hasn't yet requested any rooms. Therefore, all rooms should be available on his/her end.

View

1st Tab

```
<?php foreach($dorms as $dorm): ?>

<a class="text-decoration-none">
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-4" style="margin-left: 6rem;padding-bottom: 1rem;">
    <div class="card top-shadow" style="width: 12rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
      <div class="card-body">
       
             // TAB 1 DATA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

2nd Tab

```
<?php foreach($dormreservedas $dormres): ?>

<a class="text-decoration-none">
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-4" style="margin-left: 6rem;padding-bottom: 1rem;">
    <div class="card top-shadow" style="width: 12rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
      <div class="card-body">
       
             // TAB 2 DATA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller

```
public function home()
{
    // Check login
    if(!$this->session->userdata('student_logged_in')){
        redirect('students/login');
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Home';
    
    $data['dorms'] = $this->dorm_model->get_dorms();
    $data['dormreserved'] = $this->dorm_model->get_reserves();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('students/pages/home', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Model

On the 1st Tab, here is how I separate the requested data to be placed on the 2nd Tab

```
public function get_dorms(){
    $this->db->where('id NOT IN(select dorm_id from reserves)');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('dorms');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

2nd Tab Model

```
public function get_reserves(){
    $this->db->join('reserves', 'reserves.dorm_id = dorms.id');
    $this->db->where('reserves.tenant_id', $this->session->userdata('student_user_id'));
    $query = $this->db->get('dorms');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will works for you.

```
public function get_dorms(){
    $this->db->where('id NOT IN(select dorm_id from reserves WHERE tenant_id = '".$this->session->userdata('student_user_id')."')');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('dorms');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```